# Props array from async parent component undefined when in componentDidMount in child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, spotify

I am using the spotify API to retrieve an object called tracks which displays the name of the song and the name of the artist. The name of the track is a string but the artist is an array of objects.

the only way i am able to retrieve the information is if i create another function to call through a button click that stores the prop in state, but i want the prop information to be stored in state without the need of clicking a button.

THis is each individual track :

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import './Tracks.css';

class Track extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        console.log(props);
        super(props);
        this.state={
            artist: ''
        }
        // this.displayArtists = this.displayArtists.bind(this);
        this.componentDidMount = this.componentDidMount.bind(this);
    }

    // displayArtists(){

    //     this.setState({artist: this.props.artists[0].name});
    //     console.log(this.props);

    // }
    componentDidMount(){
        this.setState({artist: this.props.artists[0].name});
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div className="track" style={{display: 'flex', backgroundColor: "gray", border: '1px solid black', borderRadius: '5px', margin:'5px'}}>
                <h1 className="tracktitle" style={{height: 45, fontSize: 25}}>{this.props.title}</h1>
                <p style={{fontSize: 15}}>by {this.state.artist}</p>
                <button >display</button>
            </div>
        ); 
    }
}

export default Track;

Track.propTypes = {
    title: PropTypes.string,
    artists: PropTypes.array
  };
```

and here is where I am sending the props from (TracksPage.js):

```
....
  async componentDidMount(){
        spotifyApi.setAccessToken(localStorage.getItem('access_token'));
        // console.log('accesstoken', localStorage.getItem('access_token'));
        let tracks = await spotifyApi.getMyTopTracks();

        tracks.items.forEach(track => this.setState(prevState => ({
            tracks: [... prevState.tracks, {name: track.name, artist: track.artists}]
        })));

        this.setState({ tracks: this.state.tracks.slice(1) })

        // this.state.tracks.forEach(track => console.log(track.artists.name ));
        // this.state.tracks.forEach(track => this.setState({artist: track.artists[0].name}));
    }

    render(){
        return(
        <div>
            <h1>My Spotify React App!</h1>
            <div className="tracks-container" style={{maxHeight: 500, overflow: 'scroll', margin:50, marginTop:25}}>
            
            {this.state.tracks.map((track => 
                <Track key={track.id} title={track.name} artists={track.artist}/>
            ))}
            </div>
        </div>
        );
    };
}
```

When i console.log the props during the constructor call, the data shows but not when I call it in componentDidMount(). The name of track works fine but only the artists array of objects does not even though both of the props are sent together.

Answer (score 0):

try to use componentWillReceiveProps instead of using componentDidMount

```
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
if (nextProps.props.artists) {
      this.setState({
         this.setState({artist:nextProps.artists[0].name});
      });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is your issue:

```
artist: this.props.artists[0].name
```

The "artists" prop is going to pass down an array of artists from the track state to the Track component you made. You set the state to "artist" on the Track component, except you don't need `.name` if I'm correct in thinking. You already have an array of artists when you pass it down (I think you got tricked up by calling the state "artist" when it's really an array of artists, presumably.

```
tracks: [... prevState.tracks, {name: track.name, artist: track.artists}]
```

Try removing `.name` from your setState call in the Tracks component and it should fetch the first artist from the artists array (the artist at index 0).

You may also want to rewrite the second line I highlighted to `artists: tracks.artists` so it's not as confusing.

Let me know if this works!

Answer (score 0):

From what you have posted it seems the artist state isn't going to change unless the parent component state updates, so there is no reason to use state in your track component. Better to just use the prop directly.

Simply do:

```
render(){
  const artistName = this.props.artists[0].name;
  return(
    <div className="track" style={{display: 'flex', backgroundColor: "gray", border: '1px solid black', borderRadius: '5px', margin:'5px'}}>
      <h1 className="tracktitle" style={{height: 45, fontSize: 25}}>{this.props.title}</h1>
      <p style={{fontSize: 15}}>by {artistName}</p>
      <button >display</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Your also forcing the trackspage component to re-render unnecessarily with your forEach call. You can add all the new tracks at once with something like:

```
async componentDidMount(){
  spotifyApi.setAccessToken(localStorage.getItem('access_token'));
  let newTracks = await spotifyApi.getMyTopTracks();

  this.setState(prevState => ({
    tracks: [
      ...prevState.tracks,
      ...newTracks.items.map(track => ({
        id: track.id, 
        name: track.name,
        artist: track.artists
      }))
    ]
  });
}
```

Note the added `id` prop in that last snippet. You are using the id prop as a key when mapping tracks. It's vital that keys are unique, if they are all undefined you will get errors.

It's worth either using `artist` or `artists` for readability. Using both leaves you open to typo mistakes that will be hard to debug.